# select all columns which are not in another table laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables - the first one is called 'users' and the second one is called 'buy_courses'.

[image: users table]

[image]

I am trying to select all users those user_name is not in buy_courses. I tried something like -

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->rightjoin('buy_courses', 'users.user_name', '=', 'buy_courses.user_name')
                ->get();
```

It returns all users, whose user_name is in 'buy_courses', when I am using '<>', then I'm getting all users. What should be the right query?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
DB::table("users")->select('*')->whereNotIn('user_name',function($query) {

   $query->select('user_name')->from('buy_courses');

})->get();
```

just **join** actually is inner join in Laravel so actually maybe also you can try:

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('buy_courses', 'users.user_name', '=', 'buy_courses.user_name')
            ->get();
```

Comment: How does join sove the issue because it will return rows common to both ? That is not what OP expects.

Answer (score 7):

Try it using Eloquent:

```php
$courseUserNames = BuyCourses::pluck('user_name')->all();
$users = User::whereNotIn('user_name', $courseUserNames)->select(...)->get();
```

Or if you prefer using DB query:

```
$courseUserNames = DB::table('buy_courses')->pluck('user_name')->all();
$users = DB::table('users')->whereNotIn('user_name', $courseUserNames)->select(...)->get();
```

Comment: How to do this in a single query/eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

just replace `=` with `!=` , use function join

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
  ->join(
    'buy_courses', 
    function ($join)
    {$join->on('users.user_name', '!=', 'buy_courses.user_name');}
  )
  ->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use SQL's 'NOT IN'.

Example:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name NOT IN (SELECT user_name FROM buy_courses)");
```

Comment: Laravel uses PDO not *mysqli_*. You never read the question and just jumped to post an answer.